# Cannot get grub to show up (directly boots to Windows 7 instead)

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, boot-repair

Every time I try to boot, my computer goes straight into Windows 7.

I had Windows 7 installed and installed Ubuntu 14.04 afterwards, but grub does not show up on boot. Tried holding shift, messing with the grub config file on the timeout line, boot repair and other things, today I wiped the partitions I created and started all over, same result, ran boot-repair, have a look at the [boot-repair log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10017322/).

Why doesn't grub show up on my machine?

Comment: have you tried running Ubuntu live cd and from terminal    `update-grub`

Comment: I did, nothing changed :(

Comment: boot in to windows and run from cmd `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\...\grub*.efi`

Comment: boot in to windows and run from cmd `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`

Comment: You have to boot to your BIOS and select which OS to boot from your BIOS.

Comment: the windows command did not work.
Ubuntu is alreay the first option in the boot menu in my BIOS.

Comment: If Windows 7, and UEFI you should not have the secure boot nor fast boot/hibernation issues. But is hardware newer or system was Windows 8? What brand/model system. Many vendors with Windows 8 modify UEFI to only boot the UEFI entry with "Windows" in the description. That is not UEFI standard. Many systems particularily Sony & HP require work arounds so you actually boot grub using the UEFI hard drive entry which stil seems to work. http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Comment: @MiguelMendes enable legacy boot also along with UEFI and then intrupt the boot process and get in to boot menu f9 or f12 depends on your BIOS

Comment: @oldfred This is a Samsung RV520 laptop, it came with win7 by default, I had linux running before, also had some problems but boot-repair fixed them. A few months I formatted my pc and now I miss linux :P

Comment: @Mudit Legacy boot is enabled alongside UEFI.

Comment: @MiguelMendes press esc key just as your system starts booting and interrupt the boot and get in to boot options

Comment: @MiguelMendes if your system allows to disable UEFI then disable it and choose legacy boot

Comment: @Mudit When I disable UEFI the system can't even boot. Pressed Esc when booting and this menu showed up http://goo.gl/7xjx4b after selecting ubuntu nothing happens, just a blank screen

Comment: Then it may be booting? But you have video issues or black screen? http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it different model but Samsung may have same UEFI. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230919

Comment: @MiguelMendes you have to boot your Ubuntu CD as UEFI for installation

Comment: @Mudit How do I do that?

Comment: @MiguelMendes In the boot menu option select BOOT Ubuntu CD as EFI and install alongside windows

Comment: @MiguelMendes[see this also](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: I got this error:

root@ubuntu:/# grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.

After reading some more on oldfred's links I found out that I have to manually create a partition for EFI.

It says that I should not have more than 1 EFI boot partition, so I gess there is no problem in having windows and ubuntu in the same EFI boot partition_